# XSD to create an element with Namespace as prefix

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to create an XSD which can generate the following XML.

```
<note>
<email:to>abc@def.com</email:to>
<from>xyz@def.com</from>
</note>
```

How to write XSD element definition for the  element.

```
<xsd:element name="note">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="email:to" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="from" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Here the element name "email:to" fails validation.

How can I represent this in XSD?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:` symbol in XML represents [XML namespace syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace), which isn't appropriate to what you're trying to do. You can't use that symbol in XML without the processors interpreting it as a namespace.

You might want to consider using one of the two alternatives:

```
<email to="abc@def.com"/>
<email><to>abc@def.com</to></email>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would like to add some more points, Naming XML elements follow the same rule as applied for declaring variables in any programming langs,

- The characters appearing in element name can be any alpha-numeric character or underscore
- Name can start with a alpha character [numbers or _ not allowed as first char]
- **IMPORTANT** : names can't be of pattern [or cannot start with the letters)
  **xml** or **XML** or **Xml**
- Also spaces are not allowed

So abiding which certainly leads to validation error.